# Why the DrawItem method of my owner draw listbox can't be called

Tags: winapi, listbox, wtl, ownerdrawn, ondrawitem

I try to write a owner draw listbox with WTL. My code looks like this

```
template<class T, class TBase = CListBox, class TWinTraits = CControlWinTraits>
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CMyListBoxImpl : 
   public CWindowImpl< T, TBase, TWinTraits >,
   public COwnerDraw< T >
{
...
BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMyListBoxImpl)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CREATE, OnCreate)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_DESTROY, OnDestroy)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_ERASEBKGND, OnEraseBackground)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_SIZE, OnSize) 
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_DRAWITEM, OnDrawItem)
    CHAIN_MSG_MAP(COwnerDraw< T >)
    DEFAULT_REFLECTION_HANDLER()
END_MSG_MAP()

...

void Init()
{
    ...
    ModifyStyle(0, BS_OWNERDRAW | LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LBS_HASSTRINGS);
    ...
}
void DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpdis)
{
  ...
```

I also added `REFLECT_NOTIFICATIONS` in the parent's message loop, and set Owner Draw to Fixed in property sheet. But I still can't receive the message. Then I used spy++ to examine the message that the listbox receive, I found some message that is very strange (`WM_USER+7211`).
My os is WinXp and use VS2008.

Comment: ModifyStyle is too late, that flag has to turned on when the window is created.  Not sure how that's done in WTL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- BS_OWNERDRAW? That is a button style.
- Even with LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED, you still need to handle WM_MEASUREITEM.
- Some control styles (like) LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED can **only** be set when the control is created (Is that what you mean by "and set Owner Draw to Fixed in property sheet"?, if so, why modify the style in code?)

[This forum thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20151020121933/http://microsoft.public.vc.atl.narkive.com/RcXE2g7G/cownerdraw-wtl-listbox) might also be of help...